# How to get a total sum of JSON field for a certain field in Javascript 5?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this array with dictionaries and I need to get total Amount per each Code field. And also sorted by Code field. I could easily do this using HashMap or Python dict but since Hashmap doesnt exist in JS5 I have no clue how to achieve this.

```
[
  {
    "Amount":"14.00",
    "Date":"20200418",
    "Code":"151"
  },

  {
    "Amount":"5.73",
    "Date":"20200418",
    "Code":"167"
  },
  {
    "Amount":"2.00",
    "Date":"20200418",
    "Code":"151"
  }
  {
    "Amount":"3.00",
    "Date":"20200418",
    "Code":"120"
  },
]
```

So the result should be

```
120 - 3.00
151 - 16.00
167 - 5.73
```

Comment: [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: @D.Pardal I get undefined Map in ES5

Comment: You can also use an object and [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lodash it is pretty natural:

```
_.mapValues(_.groupBy(array, 'Code'), data => _.sumBy(data, d => parseFloat(d['Amount'])))
```

If you cannot use lodash (which you would need to install as a dependency), then you can do it in vanilla js

```
var groupedBy = {}

var i, d, code
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  d = array[i]
  code = d['Code']
  if (!(code in groupedBy)) {
    groupedBy[code] = parseFloat(d['Amount'])
  } else {
    groupedBy[code] = groupedBy[code] + parseFloat(d['Amount'])
  }
}
```

You can find both examples in the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/s8951jb2/2/

Comment: in my current environment I'm using Javascript 5 and it doesnt support arrows.. so i'm stuck.

Comment: @oybek.t fixed ;)

Comment: getting this error: Error: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "_" is not defined.

Comment: also this is not for front-end work... this is ES5 is being used within propriety ERP software and not even sure how I could use Iodash

Comment: @oybek.t you would need to install it as a dependency, since it is propietary ERP it might be difficult, so I've included a vanilla.js solution

Comment: this is great. Now I need to find a way to sort by keys but I guess thats another topic. Thanks much!